# Sharing data to a header that does not have a route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In Laravel I would create a view in this manner.

```
Route -> Controller -> Blade to be displayed.
```

Meaning I would create the route and point it to a controller which would return my blade view.  Any date would be passed through the controller like:

```
return view('layouts.cart')->with('cartDetails', $displayCart);
```

My question is how would I pass data to a header which is used in all the pages if there is no route for that view?

In example I have a master blade page that contains:

```
header.blade.php

a different body page each time

footer.blade.php
```

I would like the `header.blade.php` to contain some data which should display in all pages. I can do this by calling a route and using ajax to display the data but I'm wondering if there's a Laravelish way to do this.

### EDIT:

Is `View::Share` only option?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `View::share` is a way to accomplish what you need. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views):

> ### Sharing Data With All Views
>
> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views
>   that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view
>   facade's `share` method. Typically, you should place calls to `share`
>   within a service provider's `boot` method. You are free to add them to
>   the  `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to
>   house them:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Providers;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
>
> class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
> {
>     /**
>      * Register any application services.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function register()
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Bootstrap any application services.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function boot()
>     {
>         View::share('key', 'value');
>     }
> }
> ```

#### Alternative

Given that fact that you want to share the same data in many views, and specially using the `header.blade.php` -which I assume is a partial- your could [include](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#defining-a-layout) the data inside the file and insert it in your master layout.